# Liquibase- Creating index with descending ordering in column issue

Tags: scripting, liquibase

I am Facing Error :
`attribute 'descending' is not allowed to appear in element 'column'`

While running liquidate (3.5) script for creating index :
please find below code :

```
<createIndex unique="true" indexName="EMPIDX" tableName="Employee">
<Column name="JoiningDate" descending="true" />
<Column name="Empnumber" />
</createIndex>
```

also I tried :

```
<Column name="JoiningDate DESC" />
```

but this give me error : column does not exist :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run this code after making a small fix: change Column to column (change from upper case C to lower case c):

```
<createIndex unique="true" indexName="EMPIDX" tableName="Employee">
<column name="JoiningDate" descending="true" />
<column name="Empnumber" />
</createIndex>
```